# How to setup multiple alerts on single graf

Tags: alert, grafana

I want to create several alerts for logins to application. Its typical that users have login patterns:

- 00-06 01-02 users/min, more then 5 is some kind of problem
- 06-16 30-60 users/min, above 120 is some kind of a problem
- 16-24 05-10 users/min, more then 20 is some kind of problem.

Is this possible to achieve on single graf by providing multiple alerts each working in specific time range ?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is to write a synthetic series with your threshold, then alert when the delta between the actual count and the "threshold" series is greater than 0.